# What happened to the new 2.9 feature "Blueprint at the time"?

Tags: experimental-features

Some months ago Blender announced a new feature "Blueprint at the time" which would let us draw faces out of edges in kinda SketchUp-like manner. It also displayed additional blue grid under your cursor to help with incremental snapping.
It was meant to be added to v2.9 but I could no longer hear about it. Perhaps it was withdrawn due to instability?
Does anyone have clue what happened - are they still developing this feature or did they give up? It would be wonderful to have it inside Blender!

Comment: Could it be that you're referring to [this feature](https://developer.blender.org/rB122cb1a)? This will be included in 2.91.

Comment: Not quite sure. It would look like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BSBJ1X8DdYe1QBiMLXvzf3QEI0a1odZ5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Doesn't look familiar to me, could you link the video? It might also be an add-on or perhaps I've just missed the development of it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylaArhX7t9E - jump to 8:17. It was supposed to be a native feature.

Comment: Some parts of this are implemented by the feature I've linked, other parts are still in development. Blender 2.91 has a tool for adding primitive interactively. You can download the daily beta builds from [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/)

Comment: Does this mean I don't have to replace 3D cursor to put a primitive wherever I want in my model?

Comment: Yes that is correct. At least for the primitive that are currently supported by the tool. I can add this as an answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sure, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been partial implemented for Blender 2.91 as the new add object tool. It allows to control the parameters of a handful of primitives interactively. The design task for this is [T57210](https://developer.blender.org/T57210), the commit that added the feature was [rB122cb1aea823](https://developer.blender.org/rB122cb1aea82362d1b2ff3dda4fc7d309933308be)

[image: Tools in the toolbar]

[image]

[image]

[image]